# SQL query to get values of schema table row value in data table's column value

Tags: sql, join

There are 2 database tables as shown below, `Table_1` & `Table_2`.

`Table_1` column `index` is match with `id` value of `table_2`.

**Table_1**

```
| date      |city_1 | city_2 | ... | city_100 |
+-----------+-------+--------+-----+----------+
| 20.02.2018|   2   |   44   | ... |    98    |
| 21.02.2018|   1   |   25   | ... |    17    |
|    ...    |  ...  |   ...  | ... |   ...    |
```

**Table_2**

```
|  id   |   name  |
+-------+---------+
|   1   | newyork |
|   2   | london  |
|  ...  |   ...   |
|  100  | istanbul|
```

Expected result is below

```
  |  date     |   city_1   |   city_2   |  ...  |  city_100 |
  +-----------+------------+------------+-------+-----------+
  | 20.02.2018|   london   |   india    |  ...  |  canada   |
  | 21.02.2018|  newyork   |  srilanka  |  ...  |  austria  |
  |   ...     |    ...     |    ...     |  ...  |    ...    |
```

What is the SQL query to get result above?

Thanks

Comment: 100 joins will do. Some dbmses have specific options to create a table experssion from row data and pivot it back which may be a better solution. Tag your dbms.

Comment: That is a horrible table design. Can you change it?

Comment: If you have columns `City_1` through `City_100`, then that table "design" is your much bigger problem. Fix your database and make it really relational, before doing any more work ....

Comment: You should redesign the table if at all possible, to a separate relations-table. Then, a join would be trivial. Otherwise, I would look into dynamic TSQL.

Answer (score 2):

You have to join `Table_1` with `Table_2` as many as many city columns you have, like this:

```
SELECT
  t1.date, c1.name, c2.name, c3.name, ... c100.name
FROM Table_1 AS t1
JOIN Table_2 AS c1 ON t1.city_1 = c1.id
JOIN Table_2 AS c2 ON t1.city_2 = c2.id
JOIN Table_2 AS c3 ON t1.city_3 = c3.id
...
JOIN Table_2 AS c100 ON t1.city_100 = c100.id
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Postgres, you can do something like this:

```
select data.id, 
       x.names[1] as city_name_1,
       x.names[2] as city_name_2,
       x.names[3] as city_name_3
from data
  join lateral (
    select array_agg(ct.name order by e.idx) as names
    from unnest(array[city_1, city_2, city_3]) with ordinality as e(id, idx) 
      left join cities ct on e.id = ct.id
 ) x on true;
```

You still need to list all city "names" twice: once in the array inside the derived table, and once on the outside to get each name in a separate column.

If you can also live with a comma separated list of names you could use something like this:

```
select d.id, 
       string_agg(x.name, ',' order by x.idx) as names
from data d
  join lateral (
    select ct.name, e.idx
    from unnest(array[city_1, city_2, city_3]) with ordinality as e(id, idx) 
      left join cities ct on e.id = ct.id
 ) x on true
group by data.id;
```

Or you can aggregate all the names into a single JSON value, then you don't need to hardcode any column name:

```
select d.id, x.names
from data d
  join lateral (
    select jsonb_object_agg(j.col, ct.name) as names
    from cities ct 
      left join jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(d) - 'id') as j(col, id) on j.id::int = ct.id
    where j.col is not null
  ) x on true;
```

(I replaced your `date` column with an `id` column in my example)

Online example: https://rextester.com/NEBGX64778

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server (you haven't specified a DBMS), you could do something like this.

**Sample table structure and data**

```sql
CREATE TABLE sample (
  date date, city_1 int, city_2 int, city_3 int, city_n int
);

INSERT INTO sample 
VALUES 
  ('2018-02-20', 4, 44, 98, ..), 
  ('2018-02-21', 1, 25, 17, ..);

CREATE TABLE names (
  id int, 
  name varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO names 
VALUES 
  (1, 'NewYork'), 
  (4, 'London'), 
  (17, 'Istanbul'), 
  (25, 'Colombo'), 
  (44, 'Vienna'), 
  (98, 'Helsinki');
```

**Query 01**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT t1.date, t1.city, names.NAME
        FROM   (SELECT date, upvt.city, upvt.id
                FROM   sample
                       UNPIVOT ( id
                                 FOR city IN (city_1, city_2, city_3, city_n) ) upvt) t1
               INNER JOIN names ON t1.id = names.id) t2
        PIVOT ( Min(NAME)
                FOR city IN (city_1, city_2, city_3, city_n) ) AS pvt;
```

**Query 01: Output**

```
+----------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|        date          | city_1   | city_2   |  city_3  |  city_n  |
+----------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| 20/02/2018 00:00:00  | London   | Vienna   | Helsinki |   ....   |
| 21/02/2018 00:00:00  | NewYork  | Colombo  | Istanbul |   ....   |
+----------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Online Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a14672b53b457d4ae59e6c9076cd9755

---

But if you don't want to write column names (city_1, city_2, city_n), then you can use this dynamic query.

**Query 02: Get the column names**
Example: city_1, city_2, city_n

```sql
SELECT column_name
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_name = N'sample'
       AND column_name LIKE 'city_%';
```

**Query 02: Output**

```
+-------------+
| column_name |
+-------------+
| city_1      |
| city_2      |
| city_3      |
+-------------+
```

---

**Query 03: Dynamic Query**

```sql
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(max),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(max);  

SET @cols = STUFF(( SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(column_name) 
                    FROM   information_schema.columns
                    WHERE  table_name = N'sample' AND column_name LIKE 'city_%'  
                           FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'');

SET @query = 'SELECT *
              FROM   (SELECT t1.date, t1.city, names.NAME
                      FROM   (SELECT date, upvt.city, upvt.id
                             FROM   sample
                                    UNPIVOT (id
                                            FOR city IN ('+ @cols +')) upvt) t1
                             INNER JOIN names ON t1.id = names.id) t2
                      PIVOT (Min(NAME)
                             FOR city IN ('+ @cols +')) AS pvt';

--select @query;
--select @cols;

execute(@query);
```

**Query 03: Output**

```
+----------------------+----------+----------+----------+
|        date          | city_1   | city_2   |  city_3  |
+----------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 20/02/2018 00:00:00  | London   | Vienna   | Helsinki |
| 21/02/2018 00:00:00  | NewYork  | Colombo  | Istanbul |
+----------------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Online Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e2d7f10a22a3e11044fc552ff73b14c5